# Color tooltips not showing in Android Studio Flutter Project

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

I am following a flutter tutorial that is using Android Studio.  When the instructor presses ctrl+q he gets a list of color examples like so:
[What the instructor sees](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cunHL.jpg) (apologies I'm not allowed to post images yet) [And this is what I see.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoMTT.jpg)

I've already searched, and only suggestions I've found suggest:

Preferences>Editor>General>Code Completion and check the box Show the documentation popup

or Preferences>General>Other>Show quick documentation on mouse move.

Both are checked and have 500ms and 1000ms in the settings respectively but I still don't see the color list.  No amount of turning one on and the other off, or changing their ms delay values seems to pop up the box with colors, only the text box.  Pressing ctrl+q again simply opens the tooltip up in a tab in Android Studio.

Anyone know what I can do to fix this please?

Comment: You can find a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62017394/flutter-not-showing-list-of-color-swatches-for-colors-in-android-studio

Comment: Hey Mickey, thanks a lot!  You should have written that as an Answer so I could give you the upvote!  Downgrading my dart plugin to 192.7761 worked, and now the swatches show up.  Thanks again!