# Flutter not showing list of color swatches for colors in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter

My flutter project in Visual Studio Code shows color swatches but in Android Studio, it doesn't. If I want to see the colors I have to go to `colors.dart`.

Image of Android Studio:

[image: Android Studio screenshot]

Image of Visual Studio Code:

[image: Visual Studio Code screenshot]

How can I make the color swatches visible in Android Studio?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually I have this Android Studio build:

```
Android Studio 3.6.3
Build #AI-192.7142.36.36.6392135, built on April 14, 2020
Runtime version: 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04 amd64
```

And for this version the corresponding latest Dart plugin version is `192.8052` released on May, 14.

I tried it on 3 different machines, after the Dart plugin update from version `192.7761` to version `192.8052` via Tools > SDK Manager > Plugins > Dart

Dart Plugin Update Interface:

[image: Dart Plugin Update Interface]

In all cases tooltip stopped showing color swatches, like in your case. Uninstalling the Dart plugin v. `192.8052` and using the plugins interface, you can download the previous versions for the build `192.5728 — 192.*` of Android Studio from [this page](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart/versions) (to do so click on show more until Nov 19, 2019).

Download version `192.7761` and install it like so:

[image: Install From Disk]

After restarting the IDE you can see color swatches.

I don't think it's the best solution, but I think there will be a new update soon.
However, if you want the latest version of the plugin you can always update it again.

Comment: Thanks Mickey That was best Solution.I appreciate that You made my day.now it works

Comment: For Android Studio 4 you may use a more recent version 193.6911.31 (Mar 25, 2020) - also works

Answer (score 0):

It has been fixed, please update Dart plugin to version `193.7547`

[image: Dart plugin]