# Flutter Android Studio Color Palette not showing

Tags: android-studio, flutter

Recently I started learning flutter, I am trying to change the color. The Tutor on her screen when typing `Colors.` The IDE automatically shows color palettes whereas in my case it doesn't. 
I tried the following options:

> Settings -> Editor -> General -> [checkbox]Show quick documentation on mouse
>   move

> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Code Completion -> [checkbox]Insert selected
>   suggestion by pressing space, dot or other content-dependent keys &
>   [checkbox]Show the documentation popup in .... ms 
>   It doesn't work on any of those.
>   I've attached the screenshot. 
>   Tutor Screenshot:
>   [image]
>   My Screenshot:
>   [image: Mine Image]

Comment: What OS are you and the tutor running on?

Comment: I'm running Windows 10 and she is Mac

Comment: what is your android studio version ?

Comment: Just downloaded 2 days ago. Sorry I can't look into my PC as I'm outside.

Comment: I have the same problem on AS 3.6.3 and flutter 1.17.1 and flutter 1.17.2. Impossible to have the flutter color palette in editor.

Comment: working on android studio v3.6 linux; v4.0 windows. but not on intellij linux.

Comment: Not working for me, windows 10, android studio 4.0. Enabled quick documentation too.

Comment: You should downgrade your Dart plugin - 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62049796/5571200

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Color palette is part of Quick Documentation.

So, put the mouse cursor over the `Colors` class or the `color name` as bellow:

[image]

And then, go to View -> Quick Documentation, or use the shorthand key

- *Windows - CTRL+Q*
- *MacOS - F1*

[image]

When the help panel has been shown, you can scroll down and see all available colors.

[image]

Viewing over `color name`

[image]