# Flutter not showing list of color swatches for a color in Android Studio

Tags: flutter

My flutter project in Visual Studio Code shows color swatches but in Android Studio, it doesn't.

Comment: This should help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62017394/flutter-not-showing-list-of-color-swatches-for-colors-in-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

it looks like your IDE or plugins are outdated, so that they're not compatible.

Solution : update Android Studio, update all of the plugins/extensions, then reboot your system.

If doing all this didn't worked then try to reinstall the plugins.
Hope this may work for you..